# How to create words within a Forth definition

Tags: definition, forth, gforth

I'm using [Gforth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gforth), and I want to create a word in a definition. In the cmd line of Gforth I can type:

```
create foo
ok
```

Or more specifically, I defined an array function that expects a size on the stack and creates a word with the address to that array:

```
: array ( n -- ) ( i -- addr)
    create cells allot
        does> cells + ;
```

So if I type `10 array foo` I can then use `foo` later.

But if I were to write `10 array foo` within another definition it gives me a compilation error. I've tried replacing foo with `s" foo"` which compiles, but it blows up at run time, saying:

> Attempt to use zero-length string as a name

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it in gforth:

```
: bar   10 s" foo" ['] array execute-parsing ;
```

Other implementations do it differently, e.g. http://pfe.sourceforge.net/words/w-header-015.html

It's not easy to do in Standard Forth, but this may be good enough:

```
: bar   10 s" array foo" evaluate ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess most of what you want to do can be done by defining words, i.e. using `create ... does> ...` This allows you to define a word with specialized behaviour.
E.g.:

```
: 2const create , ,  does> 2@ ;
```

can be used to create double constants like `2 3 2const a-double` (that stashes 2 and 3 away in `a-double`) and then `a-double` pushes two values (2 3).